# Convert XML to string to find length

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to find the length of an XML document and would like to know how to convert an XML document into a string so that I can find its length.

Comment: There's more than one way to serialize an XML DOM to a string. Thus, there's more than one possible length.

Comment: Do you want the length in bytes or in characters?

Comment: Also, the specific XML library you're using matters. We need to know if you're using lxml, minidom, ElementTree, or something entirely different.

Comment: I am using lxml and I would like the length in bytes and chars.

Comment: ...and what have you tried already?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? (Character encoding is very, very different between them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize to a unicode string (thus, getting length in characters) in Python 2:

```
root_str = etree.tostring(root_el, encoding=unicode)
root_len_chars = len(root_str)
```

To encode that unicode string in UTF-8, and get the length in bytes (for that encoding):

```
root_len_bytes = len(root_str.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use the `ElementTree.tostring()` code https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
print ET.tostring(doc)
```